# Which drupal function can you use to invoke a function stored in contrib module (e.g. in an .inc file)?

Tags: 7

Which drupal function can you use to invoke a function stored in contrib module

Comment: module_load_include() or require_once()

Answer (score 7):

You can use `module_load_include`

```
  // Load node.admin.inc from the node module.
  module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.admin');
  // Load content_types.inc from the node module.
  module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'content_types');
```

Then you will be able to call the function that is in those files.

Answer (score 5):

When you install and enable a contributed module, its functions become part of your Drupal instance runtime environment, and it can be called from other modules (including a custom module created by you).  You can call it directly - there is no need to go through a specific function.

Like the Drupal core, some contributed modules has an API that is made up of functions that other modules may call.  These functions are designed to be called from other modules, and is usually better documented with the intention of letting them be used by third parties.

If your Drupal site for some reason has not enabled the module, you can still bring it into scope with the use of [`module_load_include`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_load_include/7), or with the standard PHP directive [`require_once`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php).

The difference between these two methods is that before you can call `module_load_include`, Drupal must to be loaded fully (Fully Bootstrapped).  However, it is smarter than `require_once` because it references the module's path when locating the file, using `drupal_get_path().`

Syntax:

```
 module_load_include($type, $module, $name = NULL);
```

Example:

```
 module_load_include('inc','module_name','file_name');
```

Note that you don't have to specify any path to use `module_load_include`.

On the other hand, you can use `require_once` *before* Drupal is fully bootstrapped, but you need to supply the `DRUPAL_ROOT` and the full path to the module:

Example:

```
 require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/sites/modules/contrib/file_name.inc' .
```

Otherwise, these two methods for bringing the functions in a contributed module into scope is equivalent.